# OpenLayers3 ol.Overlay changes position with no mapping changes

Tags: openlayers-3

This image is my map in Chrome maximized.

[image: Fullscreen]

This is the exact same view and zoom level after I re-sized Chrome.

[image: Resized down]

Notice how the symbol over New York is now in the Atlantic.  This seems to be true of all the symbols I load in my overlays, When displaying the map at full size all the symbols line up correctly but drift when the window is no longer maximized.  At further zoomed out levels the drift worsens with you having to zoom in as much as possible to get the correct view.

My html

```
<body>
    <div style="height: 100%; displayL flex; flex-flow:column;">
        <div id="map" style ="flex: 1 1 auto;"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

As for creating the map it's a simple view using OSM and a normal ol.Overlay added via map.addOverlay.

Can anyone suggest why this drift is happening?

**Update**

Here's the overlay being added

```
map.addOverlay(new ol.Overlay({
                        id: screenDesc.widget.id,
                        position: ol.proj.transform([screenDesc.longitude, screenDesc.latitude], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
                        positioning: 'center-center',
                        element: document.getElementById(screenDesc.widget.id)
                    }));
```

Comment: How are you initializing the overlay? especially the anchor?

Comment: Updated with the overlay being added.

Comment: I've tried removing the positioning and it behaves the same with regards to drifting away from it's coordinates when the window re-sizes.

Comment: i think it has something to do with the flex css. I tried to reproduce your error http://jsfiddle.net/uj7hr2os/ with these flex settings it beahves strange, but the overlay stays at the correct position